# Are there any products to replay IIS Logs files for load testing?

Tags: iis, load-testing

I would like to take log files from IIS and import them into a tool.  Then in that tool I would like it to generate a load testing script that includes all the requests and the timing of the requests.

It would be ideal if I could change the timing of the requests, or if the software contained some extra feature to speed up traffic until the response times were affected or reached some prior set threshold.

*Free would be best, but the cheaper the better as well*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [LogParser 2.2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24659) to extract the request URI's or [RConvLog](http://labs.rebex.net/RConvLog/) to convert the W3SVC log files to the standardised NCSA format.

Import your results in Apache JMeter's [Access Log Sampler module](https://serverfault.com/questions/84041/how-can-i-replay-apache-access-logs-back-at-my-servers-to-do-real-world-load-tes)

Replay away!

Comment: I'm not quite sure how you go from the Access Log Sampler to actual requests.