# how to stress test an apache proxy

Tags: apache-2.2, benchmark

I've a EC2 instance acting as a proxy for a webserver that are in other region.

This setup works great at the beginning but then, some users start receiving

```
Proxy error
The proxy server received and invalid response frmo an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request

Reason: Error reading from remote server.
```

I guess the connection was resetted, so I added a changed in the configuration file of apache:

```
  ProxyPass / http://.. retry=1 acquire=3000 timeout=600 Keepalive=On
```

Now, I would like to try to reproduce the problem again, is there any tool that can help me with this purpose? maybe `ab`?

Comment: Replay the logs http://serverfault.com/questions/84041/how-can-i-replay-apache-access-logs-back-at-my-servers-to-do-real-world-load-tes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [Siege](https://www.joedog.org/siege-home/). Make sure you turn on benchmark mode to really stress it. In the /etc/siege/siegerc file use

```
benchmark = true
```

As well as setting up how many concurrent users you need, and such

Here's the important parts of the config file, at least for me

```
connection = keep-alive
benchmark = true
delay = 0
```

And here's the command line. Note that you of course need to provide that file with URLs to whatever pages you want tested.

```
siege -c 50  -t5s -f /etc/siege/urls.txt -i -q
```

Comment: would you mind sharing your config file?

Comment: Sure, important parts added