# load testing based on access log recording

Tags: load-testing, stress-testing, stress

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tools for load-testing HTTP servers?](https://serverfault.com/questions/2107/tools-for-load-testing-http-servers)

I need to load test a saas system to find capacity+bottlenecks.

My preferred method is to record a few 100,000s or millions of real acess log urls and run it as test with increasing hit rate.

I've looked at several services all have their pros and cons. before I dive into them, which stress test service would you recommend specifically for the use case above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Apache Jmeter. the Best and Free
alternatively, if you want to spend money, you can go for Hp LoadRunner.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the system is trivially simple, then simply hitting URLs from a log file is not likely to exercise the system properly.  Most requests will need to encapsulate some sort of state, such as a session ID received from a previous login step.  If the system is very complex, many of the web-based services may not be able to handle it.  There are a lot of commercial tools that can do this and cost a lot less that LoadRunner (such as our [Load Tester](http://www.webperformance.com/load-testing/) product).